# missing data retrieved for weka datamining

Tags: weka

I need to retrieve data from my database to be mined with weka, but some data are missing in the concerned table, should I manually ameliorate the arff file with those missing attributes?
in my work, I have a table of persons(id, name, age, nationality, speciality, level, email, password) who will enrol in a specific course.
so according to their profile (level, speciality) and their trace (see the video of the course or no, have an account or have created a new account)  i need to determine the probability if he enrols in the course or no.
so here the missing values are see-video (yes, no) and account(new, no).
i'm new with data mining and weka, I hope the idea is clear.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to think about what it means that some data is missing. Is it missing completely at random, as if someone had taken a complete dataset and rolled dice to decide which data to remove? Or could the fact that the data is missing give you some information about the instance? For example if you have no data about whether someone created an account, perhaps it means that they refused to share this data, and people in that category are actually less likely to enrol in a course?

Some techniques, for example the commonly-used J48 tree classifier, can handle missing data. J48 essentially treats a missing value for an instance like the aggregate of that value for all the attributes where it is not missing. If the data is missing completely at random, that should give valid results.

Other techniques can't cope with missing data and if you want to use one of these you will have to remove attributes or instances from your data until none of the remaining data is missing, or replace the missing values with something to allow those attributes and instances to be used, or some combination of these methods. A typical approach is to replace missing values with the mean of the non-missing values for a numeric attribute, or the most common non-missing value of a nominal attribute, but you could also replace missing values with a different value that you choose - you could even treat 'missing' as a new, separate value of a nominal attribute.

Weka has filters that can perform these operations for you before doing the classification, so you don't have to go in and edit the .arff data yourself.